# Two different GPUs, one [virtual] monitor on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, virtualization, xen

i have two GPUs on my windows 7 guest configuration, one is virtual, but looks like a real one for windows (Cirrus VGA from qemu/XEN setup), and one is fully real, Radeon HD7870, which is dedicated for windows via PCI passthrough. The real GPU has no monitors connected, while virtual one has one monitor (displayed as qemu/xen SDL window on host OS) attached.

Now i want to do all the rendering on Radeon HD7870 and display it as a window on a virtual VGA' monitor.

How this could be done?

Comment: I don't think this will be possible. If the Radeon HD7870 processes any graphical data, it will output the display through it's own outputs. I don't think you'll be able to redirect the output.

Comment: What about offscreen rendering? Or how vnc/rdp works? Or something like [VirtualGL](http://www.virtualgl.org/About/Background)? I am sure there is got to be way to do some sort of the same thing.

Comment: Is possible I saw some youtube video,but they forget to put a simple how to